# Is it possible to import a script in a YAML Template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Repo called `devops`
My Pipeline has a resource declared called `devops`
Referencing to the template works:

```
 - template: templates/template.yaml@devops
```

in the `devops/templates/template.yaml` file I would like to add a step that executes a powershell script that is residing in `devops/scripts/myscript.ps1`

Is this possible?
What would the syntax be in the `template.yaml` file?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      filePath: scripts/myscript.ps1@devops
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```yaml
#templates/template.yaml
parameters:
- name: repo  # defaults for any parameters that aren't specified
  default: ''

steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      filePath: ${{ parameters.repo }}/scripts/myscript.ps1
```

and build definition:

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: devops
      type: github
      name: kmadof/devops-templates
      endpoint: kmadof

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: devops
- template: templates/template.yaml@devops
  parameters:
    repo: devops-templates
```

If you removed `checkout: self` you will get content of them `devops` repo directly in `(Agent.BuildDirectory)`. Please take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checkout-path) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these two repos are in same team project. Then:

Your `template.yaml` in `devops` repo should be:

```
steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      filePath: scripts/myscript.ps1
```

Your build definition in `main` repo should be:

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: devops
      type: git
      name: ProjectName/devops

steps:
- checkout: devops
- template: template.yaml@devops
```

Since `- checkout: devops` will only download the content of the repos, `scripts/myscript.ps1` is enough, we don't need `scripts/myscript.ps1@devops`. The direct cause of your issue is that Azure Devops Service won't automatically download the content of online `devops` repo to local agent. Just make sure the content of `devops` repo is download, and things will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could accomplish this is through the REST API using `System.AccessToken`.  You could have a reusable step template.

Example of what invoking the template could look like.

```yaml
- template: ../steps/internal-run-template-powershell.yml
  parameters:
    scriptPath: stages-file-server-deploy/checkApprovals.ps1
    displayName: Check Approvers
    branch: my-branch
```

And the template itself could invoke the REST API could look like the following (note that in this case I am using PowerShell, but you could use whatever suits you best, and if you want it to be cross-platform without any special agent requirements you could always create a task extension with to use the built-in node.js).

```yaml
parameters:
- name: scriptPath
  displayName: Where the script is located
  type: string
- name: displayName
  displayName: What you want this step to show up as
  default: Run script from pipeline
  type: string
- name: env
  displayName: Environment variables to pass to the script
  default: {}
  type: object
- name: repo
  displayName: Template repository
  default: your_template_repo_name
  type: string
- name: branch
  displayName: Template repository branch to use
  type: string

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: ${{ parameters.displayName }}
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      $templateRepo = "${{ parameters.repo }}"
      $script = "${{ parameters.scriptPath }}"
      $branch = "${{ parameters.branch }}"

      $authHeaders =  @{
          "Authorization" = "Basic " + ([convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.getBytes(":" + $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN)))
      }

      $uri = "$env:SYSTEM_COLLECTIONURI/$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT/_apis/git/repositories/$templateRepo/items?path=$script&api-version=5.1"
      if ($branch -ne "") {
        $uri += "&versionDescriptor.version=$branch&versionDescriptor.versionType=branch"
      }
      "Running $uri"
      invoke-webrequest -outfile .script.ps1 -headers $authHeaders -UseBasicParsing `
          $uri
      & .script.ps1
  env:
    ${{ each v in parameters.env }}:
      ${{ v.key }}: ${{ v.value }}
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

This approach avoids the root template having to pass in the name of the resource, and also avoids the template itself having to rely on the root template for this.

Note that the system access token will need to have sufficient privilege for this.  Privilege is [determined by the user "Project Collection Build Service (account)"](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/what-is-the-scope-of-the-token-in-systemaccesstoke/618929).