# Define azure-pipelines.yml for deployment

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I would like to create a pipeline for a Python function app and deploy it to Azure. I want the yml file to be configured for certain conditions.

[image]

Can I handle both deployment to staging and production in the same yml file?

How can I modify my yml file below to accommodate the above conditions? Please advice.

[image]

[image]

[Github link](https://github.com/a2441918/azure-pipelines-demo/)

Please advice. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. But you need to be aware that you want to be able to reuse artifacts from previous runs. In your pipeline:

- `build` stage should always run. So your trigger sections should look like this:

```yaml
trigger:
- staging
- production
```

I would recommend you to set `pr: none` and set tup branch policy for your repo. If you skip that part 'pr:none' or set it up for `staging` or `production` you wll get two build for each commit (one for CI, and one for PR). ([Branch policy for Azure Repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops), [Branch policies GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/configuring-protected-branches))

- for `staging` deployment stage you should add this condition

```yaml
dependsOn: Build
condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['System.SourceBranch'], 'staging'))
```

Please check if `System.SourceBranch` variable has a value like `staging` or `ref/heads/staging`.

- for `production` deployment stage you should a similar condition

```yaml
dependsOn: Build
condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['System.SourceBranch'], 'production'))
```

All this stuff requires plenty of duplication, thus I recommend you use [templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops). If there is no much differences in deployment to staging or production, you will be able to extract it and parameterized.

Comment: @Krzystof https://github.com/a2441918/azure-pipelines-demo/tree/master this is what I have. Is it wise to have two separate files, one for staging and one for prod or manage it in a single yml file itself? I also have comments in the yml file incase I missed anything here on the OP. Please advice whether my yml is good or not.

Comment: I would rather go for separate files, one for staging, one for production. It will be more readable. You can extract build stage as template and reuse it in both pipelines. And imagine what would happen if you get more environments, for me it is better to have file per env in this case. Your files looks good. :)

Comment: I have updated the above branch with the template. Could you please confirm and let me know if it looks good or should I make any changes? Thanks.

Comment: This looks good, but you can do more than that. You can create a template for deployment job and pass envrionment name as parameter. You can find example here on my [blog](http://thecodemanual.pl/2020/04/02/build-templates-on-azure-devops.html) or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61676408/is-it-possible-to-import-a-script-in-a-yaml-template/61677662#61677662 What is a bit strange there that is your pr trigger in production build. You have there pr set for staging but it actually does only build because you also have condition to allow deployment for `production` branch.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am most concerned about. I know that is wrong. For the production build, it should run only when a PR is open from staging to production and not for any other PR. How do I make that change?

Comment: If you keep trigger an pr you will have two builds for the same commit when you have pull request created. IMHO you should set `pr:none'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213934/discussion-between-a2441918-and-krzysztof-madej).